# SQL update using subqueries H2

Tags: sql, h2

I have a simple table Structure like this:

`USER_ROLE
+------------+----------------------+
| USER_ID    | USER_ROLE            |
+------------+----------------------+
| U007       | A                    |
| U007       | B                    |
| U007       | C                    |
| U008       | A                    |
| U009       | A                    |
| U009       | B                    |
+------------+----------------------+`

I would like to change a USER_ROLE to 'Z' instead 'A' and 'B' however the key is composed (USER_ID and USER_ROLE).

1) First query is set USER_ROLE to 'Z' where user have only one role from collection ('A', 'B').

`UPDATE (
  SELECT USER_ID
  FROM USER_ROLE
  WHERE USER_ROLE IN ('A', 'B')
  GROUP BY USER_ID
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) SET USER_ROLE = 'Z';`

but It doesn't work. How it should looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
update user_role set user_role = 'Z'
where user_id in (
        select user_id
        from user_role
        where user_role in ('A', 'B')
        group by user_id
        having count(*) = 1)
  and user_role in ('A', 'B');
```

Result:

```
select * from user_role;

USER_ID  USER_ROLE  CREATED   
-------  ---------  ----------
U007     A          2020-01-01
U007     B          2020-01-02
U007     C          2020-01-03
U009     A          2020-01-05
U009     B          2020-01-06
U008     Z          2020-01-04
```

Here's the data script I used in H2 1.4.197:

```
create table user_role (
  user_id varchar(10),
  user_role varchar(10),
  created date,
  primary key (user_id, user_role)
);

insert into user_role (user_id, user_role, created) values 
  ('U007', 'A', '2020-01-01'), 
  ('U007', 'B', '2020-01-02'),
  ('U007', 'C', '2020-01-03'),
  ('U008', 'A', '2020-01-04'),
  ('U009', 'A', '2020-01-05'),
  ('U009', 'B', '2020-01-06');
```